# How can I fix the "Predis\Client not found" error?

Tags: 6, caching

I have a project based on Drupal 7. I installed PHP 7.4, Redis, and php-redis on Ubuntu. I get a *Class 'Predis\Client' not found* error.

The values in the *setting.php* file for the module are the following.

```php
$conf['redis_client_interface']           = 'Predis';
$conf['cache_backends'][]                 = 'sites/all/modules/redis/redis.autoload.inc';
$conf['cache_class_cache']                = 'Redis_Cache';
$conf['cache_class_cache_menu']           = 'Redis_Cache';
$conf['cache_class_cache_drupal_get_filename'] = 'Redis_Cache';
$conf['cache_class_cache_bootstrap']      = 'Redis_Cache';
$conf['cache_class_cache_path']           = 'Redis_Cache';
$conf['cache_class_cache_field']          = 'Redis_Cache';
$conf['cache_class_cache_views']          = 'Redis_Cache';
$conf['cache_class_cache_admin_menu']     = 'Redis_Cache';
$conf['lock_inc']                         = 'sites/all/modules/redis/redis.lock.inc';
```

When I run `drush cc` the same error is show. For solving that, I re-installed Redis and php-redis, but that hasn't fixed the error.

Comment: It's unclear what Drupal version and module version you are using, Redis has no release for Drupal 6. Anyway, look in the readme files of the module how to install the Predis library for the release you have installed.

Comment: The first release created for the Redis module is for Drupal 7, and it's described as *Initial release under the "Redis" name.*

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the redis client interface `Predis` you have to install the Predis library. Composer is the recommended install method, alternatively for Drupal 7 you can still use the library folder. See  README.Predis.txt in the modules folder.

If you want to use the Ubuntu package **php-redis** then change the redis client interface to `PhpRedis`. See README.PhpRedis.txt in the modules folder.

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal 8 and above, Composer based installation, need to RUN below command

**composer require predis/predis**